# Vue JS ToDo list won't to delete all finished tasks

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a problem with 'DELETE ONLY FINISHED' button. It should delete all finished tasks. And when task is finished it change property 'finishedTask' into true. Then i get all finished tasks into array 'finished',but from that array i can't delete all at once.. I used two for loops to solve this,but unfortunately it doesn't work as it should. Down is full vue.js code.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WhySoSerious89/7w2qvc9o/7/)
[GitHub](https://github.com/ZdravkoSurlan/to-do-list/blob/master/todolist.html)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    index: 0,
    finished: [],
    todos: [],
    newTask: "",
  },
  methods: {
    addTask() {
      todo = {
        index: this.index++,
        task: this.newTask,
        finishedTask: false
      }
      if (this.newTask == '') {
        alert('Write a task!')
      }
      else {
        this.todos.push(todo);
        this.newTask = "";
      }
    },
    delete: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1)
    },
    deleteEverything: function() {
      if (this.todos.length == 0)
        alert('You dont have tasks!')
      else
        this.todos.splice(0, this.todos.length)
        this.newTask = ""
    },
    finish: function(index) {
      this.todos[index].finishedTask = !this.todos[index].finishedTask
    },
    finishEverything: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++)
        this.todos[i].finishedTask = true
    },
    deleteFinished: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
        if (this.todos[i].finishedTask == true) {
          this.finished.push(this.todos[i].index)

        }
          for (var j = 0; j < this.finished.length; j++) {
               this.todos.splice(this.finished[j], 1)

             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making additional arrays such as `finishedTasks` you can make use of `filter`:

```
deleteFinished() {
    this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.finishedTask)
}
```

Actually, most of your code can be simplified - you can use `map` to set all as finished instead of looping over the array.

JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wzmft26b/10

Comment: Thanks,this  works greaat!! I believe my code can be simplifed,but i'm new to Vue and still learning. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove the finished todos from `todos` array, you can override it like this:

```
deleteFinished: function() {
  let unfinished = []
  this.todos.forEach(todo => {
    if(!todo.finishedTask) {
      unfinished.push(todo)
    }
  })
  return this.todos = unfinished
}
```